# Docker throwing exception as The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a basic .net framework MVC web app and added logic to send logs to AWS Cloud Watch Logs using [Cloud Watch Logs SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), it **works fine in localsystem/localhost** but as soon as I dockerize the image I start getting exception. Please guide me in solving the issue.

Code:

```
    public static AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient logClient = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient("YYYYY",
                "XXXXX",
                RegionEndpoint.USEast1); 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Code removed for brevity sake
        var logGroup = logClient.DescribeLogGroups(); // This throws exception
        return View();
    }
```

Exception:

> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: 'A WebException with status
>   NameResolutionFailure was thrown.
>   WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com''

Answer (score 1):

I had to add below line of code in web.config to fix the problem.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Explanation - Docker is not known to the outside world, so when the request for API comes from dockerized app, it only makes it to the local system, and thus fails. But after enabling proxy, our system which hosts the docker acts as a proxy for the docker requests.